# Create Vehicle with Suspension?

Tags: gazebo-2.2, gazebo-3

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Is it possible to create a vehicle model in Gazebo (preferably versions 2 or 3) with a suspension system?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/7368/create-vehicle-with-suspension?/) by [K. Zeng](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/835/k.-zeng/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 103 on 2014-10-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The vehicle defined in the ackermann_vehicle metapackage (http://wiki.ros.org/ackermann_vehicle) has a shock absorber for each wheel.

---

Originally posted by [Jim Rothrock](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/408/jim-rothrock/) with karma: 247 on 2014-11-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [K. Zeng](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/835/k.-zeng/) on 2014-11-06**:
Thanks. I would just install the metapackage by downloading and extracting the ZIP from GitHub, right?

**Comment by [Jim Rothrock](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/408/jim-rothrock/) on 2014-11-19**:
Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

There are also some simple parameterized vehicle models in the `gazebo_models` repository. They were added in [this pull request](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo_models/pull-request/82/vehicle-models-with-steering-and-soft).

---

Originally posted by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) with karma: 2861 on 2014-11-03

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [K. Zeng](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/835/k.-zeng/) on 2014-11-25**:
Thanks, I was able to make 3 models based upon the ones provided by default. I just have an issue that needs to be addressed [here](http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/7570/soft-suspension-model-bounces-around/).